# Reading from three tables creating dataset and putting selected rows into the printReport(ds) function

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

What is the proper way to take these three datasets and just put it into one dataset to be taken into the printReport(ds) function? Am I doing my datasets incorrectly, do I only need to use one? How should I go about fixing this code?

```
Private Sub cmdPrint_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdPrint.Click 

   Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select CustomerName, ShipAddress1, ShipAddress2, ShipCity, ShipToState, ShipToZip FROM Customers Where CustomerID = @CustomerID", con)
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cboCustomer.Text

    Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand("Select * from LineTable where ID = @ID", con)
     cmd1.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = NextID

    Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand("Select * FROM HeaderTable where ID = @ID", con)
     cmd2.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = NextID

        Dim ds As New DataSet()


        Dim adap As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd) 
        Dim adap1 As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd1)
        Dim adap2 As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd2)

    If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Open()
        adap.Fill(ds, "Customers")
        adap1.Fill(ds, "LineTable")
        adap2.Fill(ds, "HeaderTable")
    con.Close()

    PrintReport(ds)

end sub


 Private Sub printReport(ByVal ds As DataSet)
    Dim newprintReport As New PrintReport(ds)
    newprintReport.ShowDialog()
 End Sub
```

Comment: Each query doesnt need its own DataSet - contrary to the name, a DataSet holds DataTables, not data - so one DataSet with three tables sounds like what you are trying to ask

Comment: @Plutonix so my new edit to my example should work?

Comment: @Plutonix I tried this and the dataset is only taking in the customer datatable, the other two it says I'm getting error because object reference not set to an instance of an object